# Как правильно передавать store в компоненты в mobx?

Tags: reactjs, mobx

Как лучше, передавать props в компоненты в mobx?
В коде 2 компонента Table1 и Table2.
В Table1 передаётся store и уже там из него достаются значения
А в Table2, явно указываем какие переменные нужно передать (tableHeader и rows).

```
import React , {Component} from 'react'

import Table1 from "./Table1"
import Table2 from "./Table2"

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        const {store} = this.props;

      return (
            <div>
                <Table1 
                    store={store}
                />

                <Table2 
                    store={store}
                    tableHeader={store.tableHeader}
                    rows={store.rows}
                />
            </div>
      )}
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Правильнее всего будет использовать специальную библиотеку от создателей Mobx - `mobx-react`, которая предоставляет две удобнейшие вещи: `Provider` и `inject`

- `Provider` служит для того что бы предоставить данные из вашего *Store* на любом уровне вложенности компонентов
- `inject` служит для того что бы найти выше в иерархии компонентов `Provider` и вытянуть из него нужные в данном компоненте данные

Прошу заметить, `inject` принимает как аргумент функцию обратного вызова, которая в свою очередь должна иметь первым аргументом объект (ваш *Store*) и возвратить объект который будет передан в компоненту как `props`

Все что вам нужно сделать для того что бы начать, это две вещи:

1. Обернуть ваше приложение в `Provider` и передать ему `store`
2. Использовать `inject` в нужном компоненте при этом передав ей правильную функцию обратного вызова (callback)

Для ознакомления приглашаю посетить специально подготовленный пример (ссылка ниже)

[Пример использования (CodeSandbox)](https://codesandbox.io/s/8km2kmj2k8)

---

Среди причин почему этот подход является самым правильным:

- Не нужно передавать и "жонглировать" данными сквозь всю структуру компонентов, что особенно становиться не приятным когда ваше приложение разрастается до внушительных масштабов
- Каждый компонент который использует данные из *store* имеет в том же файле код который подскажет какие именно данные он "вытягивает" из 
  *Store* посредством *Provider*